# Horizontal to Vertical View SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
oDate       value1     value2     value3     value4
2014-06-01  10         20         30         40
2014-06-02  20         25         35         50
```

I want to have the following result

```
oDate       oField     oValue
2014-06-01  Value1     10
2014-06-01  Value2     20
2014-06-01  Value3     30
2014-06-01  Value4     40
```

Is it possible to do that in SQL?
Need advice. Cheers,

Comment: [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(oDate DATETIME,value1 INT,value2 INT,value3 INT,value4 INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
('2014-06-01',10,20,30,40),
('2014-06-02',20,25,35,50)
```

**UNPIVOT query**

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
(
    SELECT
        oDate,
        value1,
        value2,
        value3,
        value4
    FROM
        @tbl
) sourceTable
UNPIVOT
(
    oField FOR oValue IN
    (value1,value2,value3,value4)
) AS unpvt
```

Reference:

- [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT ODATE,VALUE,FIELD
FROM 
   (SELECT odate,value1,value2,value3,value4
   FROM #temp) p
UNPIVOT
   (VALUE FOR FIELD IN 
      (value1,value2,value3,value4)
)AS unpvt;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
select
    oDate,
    'Value1' as oField,
    value1 as  oValue
from yourTable
union all
select
    oDate,
    'Value2' as oField,
    value2 as  oValue
from yourTable
union all
select
    oDate,
    'Value3' as oField,
    value3 as  oValue
from yourTable
union all
select
    oDate,
    'Value4' as oField,
    value4 as  oValue
from yourTable
order by oDate, oField
```